# Problem with moving JSPs under WEB-INF directory

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, web-inf

I am facing a problem when I move my JSP files along with CSS and JS files under WEB-INF/web/ directory. The problem is that, when a JSP page loads, it does not load CSS and JS files. Please help if you have any idea about it.

Thanks

Umar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you want to write controllers to serve the css/js files in the WEB-INF folder, you will need to move those files out of WEB-INF so that they can be served as static files by the app server.

Answer (score 2):

WEB-INF is not web accessible, you need to put css/js into public_html(www) as browser loads them through http.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contextPath` to retrieve any file from the foot folder,this way can work with files inside and outside WEB-INF folder.

You can make like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/fromStyle.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

To access 'WEB-INF' use

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/...");
```